# How do we add custom actions in the push notification manage options for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to add custom actions to the push notification manage options menu.
Manage options can be found by swiping left on the push notification that is received and tapping on the options button.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to do this on your phone in general or how to write code for an app you are working on that does this? This appears to be off-topic.

Comment: I am looking for some tutorials or code for adding additional actions under the options. I intend to add some more options to my app.

Comment: You can't add actions to that menu. You can associate actions with a long tap of your notification https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types